# Speed- Up Merging dataframes based on special criteria

Tags: r, dataframe

I got two data frames with structures(columns) below:

```
Price ["CID","Startdate","Enddate","P1","P2"] 

Usage ["Date","Hour","CID","Value"]
```

I am trying to merge Price with Usage. I want P1 and P2 values inside 'Usage' by checking for corresponding 'CID' and 'Date' values in 'Price'

This is my R code below:

```
t_cid=Price$CID

Startdate=Price$Startdate
Enddate=Price$Enddate


fv <-function(x){  

p<-Price[ (t_cid==x[3]) & (x[1] >=Startdate ) &(x[1] <=Enddate),c("P1","P2")] 
return(list(p)) 
}

t1=Sys.time()

k=unlist(apply(Usage,1,fv))

t2=Sys.time()

print(t2-t1)

v=rep(c(TRUE,FALSE),length(k)/2)

Usage$P1=k[v]
Usage$P2=k[!v]
```

Vector v to seperate P1 and P2 values from k

Resultant Dataframe: Usage

```
["Date","Hour","CID","Value","P1","P2"]
```

This logic works.But I would like to increase the speed manifold(6-10 times). Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider using the "data.table" package ... http://www.openanalytics.eu/blog/need-processing-speed-datatable

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` is awesome.

At first: Next time, please provide some sample data, to illustrate what your data actually looks like. It helps to see what additional information one can use. I made up a sample myself and please have a look if I got it more or less right.

```
Price <- data.table(
    CID = rep(c(1, 2), 1, each = 5), 
    Startdate = rep(seq(Sys.Date(), by = "2 day", length.out = 5), 2), 
    Enddate = rep(seq(Sys.Date() + 1, by = "2 day", length.out = 5), 2),     
    P1 = runif(10), P2 = rnorm(10)
)

Usage = data.table(
    Date = rep(seq(Sys.Date(), by = "2 day", length.out = 4), 2), 
    Hour = 6:13, 
    CID = rep(c(1, 2),2, each = 2), 
    Value = runif(8)
)
```

Note that these are already defined as `data.tables`. Just run `dt <- data.table(df)` to create a `data.table` from any `data.frame`

So here is your deal:

```
Usage[ , P1 := Price[.BY$Date >= Startdate & .BY$Date <= Enddate & CID == .BY$CID, P1], by = c("Date", "CID")]
Usage[ , P2 := Price[.BY$Date >= Startdate & .BY$Date <= Enddate & CID == .BY$CID, P2], by = c("Date", "CID")]
```

Assumtions made: There is only one row in `Price` for each combination of `CID`and `Date` in `Usage`.

Check out `data.table` documentation for more information, since this would probably blow up this post.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. This is exactly what I was looking for!!   Data.table is really cool. I will check out the data.table documentation.